# Remove featured image from the WooCommerce gallery if gallery exist

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to remove the featured image from woocommerce gallery, but only if gallery exist.

I have tried *"[Remove featured image from the WooCommerce gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732859/remove-featured-image-from-the-woocommerce-gallery/44732989#44732989)"* answer code to remove the image, but also removes from other products too that don't have gallery, leaving the product without the main image.

I know that Wordpress has a function `get_post_gallery()` to check this, but what about woocommerce?

So, my main question is: How to check if a product gallery exist to implement this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add follows code snippet -

```
function woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html( $html, $attachment_id ) {
    global $product;
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

    return ( $attachment_ids && $product->get_image_id() == $attachment_id ) ? '' : $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me with this matter. hope this code help others...

Comment: Worked for me. The only issue that I had, was variable product thumbnails which were updated to the featured image when any of the variations were chose. Solved it by commenting out this `o.wc_set_variation_attr("src",t.image.gallery_thumbnail_src),` in `add-to-cart-variation.min.js`.