# Remove featured image from WooCommerce gallery/lightbox thumbnails only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, lightbox

I am in need to hide the featured product image from wordpress woocommerce gallery/lightbox but it still has to show up as big image in the product page. I have tried several snippets such as [Remove featured image from the WooCommerce gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732859/remove-featured-image-from-the-woocommerce-gallery/67040436#67040436) but those snippets end up removing either the featured img both from gallery and product page or the gallery/lightbox itself.

Please see attached img link.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please provide website url?

Comment: https://gamingaddicted.it/prodotto/handpicked-red-chillies/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible to do this with your css. But remember one thing. To hide the first thumbnail is not always a good idea because when someone will click on another image from your image gallery then you will loose the first featured image so the customer may not see the main product.

```
.woocommerce div.product div.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 .flex-control-thumbs li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Lubo thanks for your reply and for the above css which works neatly :)
The concept is that i will make the images in the gallery not clickable, i want to use the galley only to highlight main components assembled in the pc.
Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: No problem, you are welcome. Glad to help. I would appreciate a vote up if its possible. Have a great day! :)

Comment: i did vote but i'm a new user, looks like it wont reflect on the topic

Comment: Oh, thats right. Thank you anyway! Have a great day :)

Comment: hey Lubo, with the code above, the first row of the thumbs displays 3 thumbs, while the 2nd row displays 4 thumbs, do you have a quick fix for that please? Thanks!